# Two Aggregate Results in one list

Tags: apex, map, aggregateresult

I've changed the code again, but I still get an error.

But now I get the error:
Constructor not defined: [VTP31_class.CombinedSummary].(AggregateResult, AggregateResult) in row 35, column 35

**CLASS**

```
    Public Class VTP31_class {

    Public VTP31_class() {

    }

public class CombinedSummary {
    public Integer CountAcc {get; set;}
    public Id UId {get; set;} 
    public Integer CountSales {get; set;}
    public Double Brutto_BWS {get; set;}  
}

Public List<CombinedSummary> generateWrappers() {
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> AccMap = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>();
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> AccSales = new Map <Id, AggregateResult>();
        //Set<Id> AccSet;
        List<CombinedSummary> combinedSummaries = new List<CombinedSummary>();

        FOR(AggregateResult ar: [SELECT COUNT(OwnerId) CountAcc, Id FROM Account GROUP BY Id]) {
            AccMap.put((Id)ar.get('Id'), ar);
        }

        FOR(AggregateResult ar: [SELECT COUNT(Id) CountSales, SUM(BWS_Brutto__c) Brutto_BWS, Parent2__r.Parent1__r.Account.Id FROM Sales__c GROUP BY Parent2__r.Parent1__r.Account.Id]) {
            AccSales.put((Id)ar.get('Id'), ar);
        }

        Set<Id> AccSet = new Set<Id>();
        AccSet = AccSales.keySet();
        AccSet.addAll(AccSales.keySet());

        FOR (Id Id : AccSet) {
            combinedSummaries.add(new CombinedSummary(AccMap.get(Id), AccSales.get(Id)));
        }

        Return combinedSummaries;

}
```

**PAGE**

```
still open
```

---

EDIT 27.11.2018

I've added the following code as constructor, but it still not works.

```
public CombinedSummary (AggregateResult ar) {
    CountAcc = (Integer) ar.get('CountAcc');
    UID = (Id) ar.get('Id');
    CountSales = (Integer) ar.get('CountSales');
    Brutto_BWS = (Double) ar.get('Brutto_BWS');
    }
```

---

EDIT 04.01.2019

CLASS shows no more errors:

```
Public Class VTP32_class {

    public String CombinedSummary { get; set; }

Public VTP32_class() {

}

Public class CombinedSummary {
    public Integer CountAcc {get; set;}
    public Id UId {get; set;} 
    public Integer CountSales {get; set;}
    public Double Brutto_BWS {get; set;}  

Public CombinedSummary (AggregateResult arM, AggregateResult arS) {
    CountAcc = (Integer) arM.get('CountAcc');
    UID = (Id) arS.get('Id');
    CountSales = (Integer) arS.get('CountSales');
    Brutto_BWS = (Double) arS.get('Brutto_BWS');
    }
}

Public List<CombinedSummary> generateWrappers() {
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> AccMap = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>();
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> AccSales = new Map <Id, AggregateResult>();

        List<CombinedSummary> combinedSummaries = new List<CombinedSummary>();

        FOR(AggregateResult arM: [SELECT COUNT(OwnerId) CountAcc, Id FROM Account GROUP BY Id]) {
            AccMap.put((Id)arM.get('Id'), arM);
        }

        FOR(AggregateResult arS: [SELECT COUNT(Id) CountSales, SUM(BWS_Brutto__c) Brutto_BWS, Einzelrisiko__r.Gruppenvertrag__r.Unternehmen__r.Id FROM Umsatz__c GROUP BY Einzelrisiko__r.Gruppenvertrag__r.Unternehmen__r.Id]) {
            AccSales.put((Id)arS.get('Einzelrisiko__r.Gruppenvertrag__r.Unternehmen__r.Id'), arS);
        }

        Set<Id> AccSet = new Set<Id>();
        AccSet = AccSales.keySet();
        AccSet.addAll(AccSales.keySet());

        FOR (Id Id : AccSet) {
            combinedSummaries.add(new CombinedSummary(AccMap.get(Id), AccSales.get(Id)));
        }

        Return combinedSummaries;

}

}
```

PAGE, the output does not work, I get the error "Unknown property 'VTP32_class.generateWrappers'"

```
<apex:page controller="VTP32_class" sidebar="false">   

<apex:repeat value="{!generateWrappers}" var="var">
    {!var['AccSales'].CountSales}
</apex:repeat>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what you need?

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the wrapper class pattern you are already using with the `Summary1` and `Summary2` objects. Call a new object `CombinedSummary`, for example:

```
public class CombinedSummary {
    public Integer Anz {get; set;}
    public Double Amount_BWS {get; set;}      
    public Integer Anz{get; set;}
    public Double BWS {get; set;}    
    public Double JZ {get; set;}      
    public Id OwnerId {get; set;}
}
```

Include in that wrapper class the combined set of fields from the two aggregate queries, as above, but only one field for the owner.

Then you'll need to construct some Maps keyed on the shared value between these two queries - the `OwnerId` / `Sales_Rep__c`. Something like this, for example:

```
List<CombinedSummary> generateWrappers() {
    Map<Id, AggregateResult> oppMap = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>();
    Map<Id, AggregateResult> salesMap = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>();
    Set<Id> ownerSet;
    List<CombinedSummary> combinedSummaries = new List<CombinedSummary>();

    for (AggregateResult ar : [SELECT COUNT(Id) Anz, SUM(Amount_BWS__c) Amount_BWS, SalesRep__c FROM Sales__c GROUP BY SalesRep__c]) {
        salesMap.put(ar.get('SalesRep__c'), ar);
    }

    for (AggregateResult ar : [SELECT COUNT(Id) Anz, SUM(Amount) BWS, SUM(JZ__c) JZ, Account.OwnerId FROM Opportunity GROUP BY Account.OwnerId]) {
        oppMap.put((Id)ar.get('OwnerId'), ar);
    }

    ownerSet = new Set(salesMap.keySet());
    ownerSet.addAll(oppMap.keySet());

    for (Id ownerId : ownerSet) {
        combinedSummaries.add(
            new CombinedSummary(
                salesMap.get(ownerId),
                oppMap.get(ownerId)
            )
        );
    }

    return combinedSummaries;
}
```

This is a little rough but I think you can see the outline of the solution. You'd need then to implement a constructor for `CombinedSummary` that accepted one of each type of `AggregateResult` and populated its fields accordingly, taking care to handle `null` parameters safely.

The signature of your constructor should be

```
public CombinedSummary(AggregateResult salesAR, AggregateResult oppAR) {
```

Comment: Thanks David, I've changed the code but now I get an error. Could you help me again.

Comment: You have to cast the result of `ar.get()` to an `Id`. Apologies, I forgot that in my code.

Comment: Thanks David, I think we are close to the end, but now get an error. Could you please help me again.

Comment: The error you're getting really means just what it says. You must actually write the constructor for the `CombinedSummary` class, as I mentioned above. It can follow a similar pattern to what you already created in your other wrapper classes.

Comment: Just so you know, it's helpful to preserve the original context (your first question) so that future readers will understand the answers. You can definitely open further questions if you have detailed follow-ups (beyond a quick comment).

Comment: That is what I still not understand with the constructior. The code is all what I have in this class-file. Could you help me with the structure for the class. I thought it would be better here to discuss the question further. For the future I will change my doing.

Comment: In the first version of your code, you had constructors defined on your wrapper objects, like `public summary2 (AggregateResult ar2)`. You need to write that method on your `CombinedSummary` class, taking two `AggregateResults` and populating the fields in the wrapper objct from them.

Comment: I tried to add the constructor, but it still not works. Could you help me again.

Comment: Your constructor needs to take *two* `AggregateResult` parameters - one from each query.

Comment: Now my Class is working without errors, but I can't display the results, because I get an error. I've added the whole actual code to my question above (edit 04.01.2019)

Comment: Please open new questions for separate follow-ups.

Comment: Hey David, I start a new post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245617/two-aggregate-results-in-one-list-continue Thanks