# Two Aggregate Results in one list (continue)

Tags: map, aggregateresult

This post is the continue from [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237659/two-aggregate-results-in-one-list).
David told me it is better to start a new post.

My class is fine so far, I get no error.
But if I try to display the results, I get an error "Unknown property 'VTP32_class.generateWrappers'".

**CLASS**

```
Public Class VTP32_class {

    public String CombinedSummary { get; set; }

Public VTP32_class() {

}

Public class CombinedSummary {
    public Integer CountAcc {get; set;}
    public Id UId {get; set;} 
    public Integer CountSales {get; set;}
    public Double Brutto_BWS {get; set;}  

Public CombinedSummary (AggregateResult arM, AggregateResult arS) {
    CountAcc = (Integer) arM.get('CountAcc');
    UID = (Id) arS.get('Id');
    CountSales = (Integer) arS.get('CountSales');
    Brutto_BWS = (Double) arS.get('Brutto_BWS');
    }
}

Public List<CombinedSummary> generateWrappers() {
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> AccMap = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>();
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> AccSales = new Map <Id, AggregateResult>();

        List<CombinedSummary> combinedSummaries = new List<CombinedSummary>();

        FOR(AggregateResult arM: [SELECT COUNT(OwnerId) CountAcc, Id FROM Account GROUP BY Id]) {
            AccMap.put((Id)arM.get('Id'), arM);
        }

        FOR(AggregateResult arS: [SELECT COUNT(Id) CountSales, SUM(BWS_Brutto__c) Brutto_BWS, Einzelrisiko__r.Gruppenvertrag__r.Unternehmen__r.Id FROM Umsatz__c GROUP BY Einzelrisiko__r.Gruppenvertrag__r.Unternehmen__r.Id]) {
            AccSales.put((Id)arS.get('Id'), arS);
        }

        Set<Id> AccSet = new Set<Id>();
        AccSet = AccSales.keySet();
        AccSet.addAll(AccSales.keySet());

        FOR (Id Id : AccSet) {
            combinedSummaries.add(new CombinedSummary(AccMap.get(Id), AccSales.get(Id)));
        }

        Return combinedSummaries;

}

}
```

**PAGE**

```
<apex:page controller="VTP32_class" sidebar="false">   

<apex:repeat value="{!generateWrappers}" var="var">
    {!var['AccSales'].CountSales}
</apex:repeat>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to use a value in a `value` attribute, you need a getter either by way of a variable, or by prefixing the function by "get". So, with minimal effort, you can simply change one line of code:

```
Public List<CombinedSummary> getgenerateWrappers() {
```

Note that the VF does not change at all; the "get" is prefixed in front of the method name in `value="{!generateWrappers}"` for you.

The alternative would be to have a variable like this:

```
public CombinedSummary[] summaryList { get; set; }
```

At which point, you'd have to run another method to generate the results (e.g. in your constructor). This would require a slightly larger change (in addition to the new line of code).

```
Public VTP32_class() {
  summaryList = generateWrappers();
}
```

And use the new variable:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!summaryList}" var="var">
```

Comment: I've added the get to the public list, but now I get the info at the visualforce "collection is ready only", what is the meaning of that?

Comment: @peXeq Just that you can't add/remove elements.`AccSet.addAll(AccSales.keySet());` is your culprit here; you can't add values to the keyset of a map. If you need a set you can use, you'd have to clone the original set first (`AccSet = new Set<Id>(AccSales.keySet());`)